# How to fix an error of Docker Desktop 'job failed with message: 'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start' on Window Server 2019?

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016, docker-desktop

When I try to run installed Docker Desktop I got an error. How can I fix it?

```
System.InvalidOperationException: job failed with message: 'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID 443C0D91-1225-4EBB-9782-9EE15C42F9C6)

The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (Virtual machine ID 443C0D91-1225-4EBB-9782-9EE15C42F9C6).    at Docker.Backend.HyperVInfrastructure.HandleUpdatedJob(CIMConcreteJob updatedJob) in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperVInfrastructure.cs:line 772    at Docker.Backend.HyperVInfrastructure.<HandleMaybeAsyncJob>d__40.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperVInfrastructure.cs:line 706
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at Docker.Backend.HyperVInfrastructure.<StartVMAsync>d__32.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperVInfrastructure.cs:line 554
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Docker.Backend.HyperV.<StartAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperV.cs:line 105
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Docker.Backend.HttpAPI.HyperVController.<StartAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17739\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HttpAPI\HyperVController.cs:line 49
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
```